# Best way to validate an external gem's ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

What is the best way to add validations to an external Gem's activerecord model?

```
module Library
    class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
       validates :field_active, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
    end
end
```

I would like to add another `validates` to it e.g.

```
validates :me_too, presence: true
```

But since it's an external gem, it's not really possible to just add it below `validates :field_active`.

I would like to know what the best practice way of doing this is.
Is `class_eval` the best way or is that frowned upon?

Comment: This code looks like it should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: That code works (it's a representation of the Model as defined by the Gem), I was asking for the best practice way to add another `validates` call to the `Library::Model`. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has so-called "open classes". You can open any class (at any time) and add more methods to it. This should work:

```
module Library
  class Model
    validates :me_too, presence: true
  end
end
```

It opens already defined `Library::Model` and just adds one more line of code to what's already there (not replacing/removing that existing code).

Note that this depends on `Library::Model` being already *loaded* (this is not guaranteed). This should be a safer alternative:

```
Library::Model.instance_eval do
  validates :me_too, presence: true
end
```

It will trigger loading of `Library::Model` if it's not already loaded.

Comment: Wow, you learn something new everyday. Where am I supposed to add this?. It's given me an `LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Model, expected /var/www/my_app/app/models/model.rb to define it)` error. I declared this in a random model file.

Comment: @Passerby Try putting it in an initializer: `config/initializers/library_patches.rb`

Comment: You are a godsend!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Sergio, shouldn't this be a `class_eval` rather than `instance_eval`? And I take it the eval code is best placed in an initializer as well?

Comment: @Passerby: I understand the confusion. At a first glance, instance_eval/class_eval are counter-intuitive, until you understand the hidden logic. `instance_eval` runs code in the context of this very object. Which happens to be `Library::Model`, an instance of class `Class`. See [this example](https://eval.in/965783) and [this article](https://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval/).

Comment: Thanks so much for all the insight. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: For future googlers, this is a [really good article](https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs142-winter15/classEval.php) explaining the differences in an easy to digest way.